# Location of files when using @example tag with roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen2

When documenting a function with roxygen2 it is possible to place examples in a separate file.

See here: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html
"Instead of including examples directly in the documentation, you can put them in separate files and use @example path/relative/to/packge/root to insert them into the documentation."

and here: http://roxygen.org/roxygen2-manual.pdf

e.g.

```
#' Add together two numbers.
#' 
#' @param x A number.
#' @param y A number.
#' @return The sum of \code{x} and \code{y}.
#' @example /path/to/example/add.R
add <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}
```

My question is: what path should be used to store the example R files?

Comment: I think /inst/ moves to / when installing the package? I guess this won't matter though if the documentation is already built?

Comment: Yes `inst/examples` should move to `examples` and I would think you could then reference `/examples` in your documentation.

Comment: OK inst/examples works well. I can reference /inst/examples/file.R in the source code, then create documentation with devtools::document(). /inst/examples moves to /examples, but I think this is irrelevant as the documentation is already built...

Comment: I can't decide if this is a good idea or not. It makes it a bit easier to run your examples, but isn't the whole point of roxygen that you keep the documentation right next to where the function is defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The appropriate location for examples used in your roxygen is:

```
inst/examples/
```

The roxygen line then should be:

```
#' @example inst/examples/add.R
```

---

Is this good practice?  I think it is, since:

- It makes it easier to run, modify and test the examples whilst developing
- It makes it possible (in principle, at least) to re-use the examples in different places in the documentation, e.g. in the vignette

Comment: I find it useful when I have many lines for the examples with indentation that I want to preserve. Most of the time I still use @examples though.